# Can't get the tags from controller in checkbox

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravelcollective

Can't get the tags from controller in checkbox

In `Controller`:

```
$tags = Tag::pluck('name','id')->all();
return view('admin.posts.create', compact('categories','tags'));
```

In `view`:

```
{!! Form::label('tag_id','Select Tag') !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('tags[]',$tags,false,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the tags

```
@foreach($tags as $tag)
    {!! Form::checkbox('tags[]', $tag->id, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    {!! Form::label('tags', $tag->name) !!}
@endforeach
```

Hope it's helpful.